# Cannot access 192.168.7.2 on BeagleBone Black

Tags: beagleboard, beagleboneblack

I just bought my BBL for about 1 week. It works well until today, I don't know why I cannot access to 192.168.7.1 . When I try to access, it just display "Cannot GET /". I still normally access to Cloud9 IDE and SSH. How can I fix this issue ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it turned out that I had moved the /var/lib/cloud9 directory when trying to fix cloud9 not loading (still not loading btw), but it turns out that the entire beaglebone black internal website is inside that folder as well. So if you're missing that folder you will have this issue.